# Chartjs - Changing legend as a line with pointsyle of circle?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, label, legend

```
      const myLineChart = new Chart(viewsCount, {
      type: 'line',
      data: lineChartStats.data,
      options: {             
        elements: {
          line: {
              tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
          },
          point: {
          pointStyle: 'line'
         }
          },           
       
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: "top",
          align: "start",   
          labels: {
            boxHeight: 3
            usePointStyle : true,            
          }                           
        }
}
```

Chartjs - Changing legend as a line with pointsyle of circle? What can I do to style the legend I'm using latest cdn of chartjs

Answer (score 0):

Please read the migration guide to chart.js version 3, it has some.breaking changes for example legend config has been moved to the plugins section so you will have to do `options: { plugins: { legend: {} } }`

After that it should work, otherwise they have an example online where you can look at to see what's different https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/point-style.html

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. But I already use that one I think the legend label is based on the point style for example you use line style then the point will be just as the legend, line.